# Conversion of varchar to date type in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to convert `varchar` field which is in format `dd.mm.yyyy` to date type field in SQL SERVER 2008.

I used approach like `convert(datetime, left(yourDateField, 2) + '01 20' + right(yourDateField, 4), 100)` but unable to so.

Is there any way to convert `Varchar` string which is in format `dd.mm.yyyy` to `Date type` in SQL?

Comment: Does this varchar field also contains other stuff than dates ? If not than change the type to Date. Never never never ever store dates as varchar

Comment: you want to convert Varchar (dd.mm.yyyy) to Datetime ?

Answer (score 2):

```
select convert(date,dateField,104)
from tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)= '21.11.2016';
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@String,103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Datetime to Varchar

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),104)
```

Varchar to Datetime

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,yourfeild,104)
```

[Refer this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Comment: How does this answer the question asked?

Comment: Its strange. In some cases it works and in some cases getting "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." error

Comment: @rahul16590 Please let me know the case with this out-of-range value error

Comment: @GuruprakashC when I used  query like this  select * 
from PTP14
where CONVERT(datetime, LTRIM(RTRIM([Start])), 104) Like ''    I got this error where Start field is nvarchar with values are in dd.mm.yyyy format

Comment: @rahul16590 Please let me know the value of LTRIM(RTRIM([Start])). If it is correct date format. It will not throw error.

Answer (score 0):

If Your date field is not in proper datetime format then this type of Out of range value error will occurred.

If your date field is in proper datetime format then you can easily convert varchar field to datetime format.

see example:

```
select CONVERT(datetime,'2016-11-21 01:02:12') 
select CONVERT(datetime,'2016-11-31 01:02:12') 
select CONVERT(datetime,'2016-11-21 00:00:01 PM')
```

In above Example,First query get easily converted to datetime
but second and third query will give error as out of range value. because 31 Nov is invalid date. and 00:00:00 PM is also wrong date format.

IF your field is in correct format 
then simply try any one of the below query

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)= '21.11.2016';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@String,104)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@String,103)
```

Hope so, you get what I am trying to say.